# Hiding specific contact

Tags: lightning-experience

so we are a pediatrics and we use Salesforce. One of the roles Salesforce plays in our practice is when a patient's parent calls our call center, based on the phone number the patient's information shows up on our end. So for example lets say a mother has 3 child and calls our call center, we would be able to see all her children, then we would ask who is she calling in regards to. Now my question is, lets say one of the child is deceased and every time the mother calls we don't want our call center users to mention about her deceased child and ask her about the child, therefore is how can we hide the patient without deleting there information. So is there a way to hide a specific contact on salesforce for certain users?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Right now, I don't think there's enough information for someone to give you a very targeted answer. Including more information about the things you're using in Salesforce would  help. For example, it sounds like you have some CTI (Computer Telephony Integration) in place. Knowing what that is would be helpful. Also, knowing what your call center is looking at (a User or Account record, a custom lightning component or visualforce page, etc...) would be helpful to narrow down the possible solutions. You can [edit] your question to add info.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is to add, modify, or just generally use a picklist or a record type to capture this additional aspect of your patients (Deceased, Child, Adult, etc...). Once you have a way to categorize certain records, you gain a variety of ways to _filter_ those records.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things you could do. Coming from the b2b world we use a checkbox or picklist to flag active and inactive accounts. You could take the same concept and have some sort of active/alive status to quickly let your reps know who they ask about. It's an incredibly sensitive area so the name you use for this field would have to be thought about real hard on how you would flag them but I feel like that's the best way to do this. Put the field up near the top of the page so the users don't miss it.

You could also create a custom visualforce page to programatically hide the records you don't want to show.

I don't think you should hide the record but if you really have your heart set on it you could make your Contact sharing settings set to private and then open it up based on sharing rules or move the deceased contact above the users in the role hierarchy which would essentially "hide" it from the end users who would be down below admins or managers if that makes sense. Controlled By Parent the other option not public would make all the contacts under an account show or hide which wouldn't work because you want to see some but not others.